# Deleting contents of silverlight isolated storage from an MSI

Tags: silverlight, winapi, windows-installer

I have a scenario where an MSI needs to delete the contents of the silverlight isolated storage directory for a particular silverlight app.  Since the location of isolated storage for my app is different from user-to-user/machine-to-machine, the MSI can't do this directly and needs to call out to some sort of script/executable to get the job done.  So my question is two parts

1. What's the best way to determine what the location of silverlight isolated storage is for a particular silverlight app?  My current thinking is walk all the folders underneath `<User>\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is\` and find an `id.dat` file that matches my app.
2. What framework/language should I use to write a program to do (1) above and then delete the contents of the folder?  I would like to have as few external dependencies as possible; e.g., I could easily do this with .NET, but then my MSI would require the user to have .NET just to delete a couple of files (unfortunately, unacceptable).

For (2), I'm thinking a straight win32 app or a vbscript, but I have no experience with win32, and I'm not sure of any hurdles I may need to jump through if people have disabled vbscript for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the directory I'd just write an empty file with a GUID - maybe even the assembly GUID. That way you don't have to crack open the file, you just do a file scan and find the GUID match and there is your directory.

To do the deletion, you can just use either CScript or VBScript and the WScript host (Google those and you'll see scads of examples).

Comment: I guess I should have just asked you in the first place =p

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it with an MSI, but what about reversing the problem?  Instead of using an MSI, you could create a service that the Siverlight client checks on startup and, depending on the return value, the client could clear its own isolated storage.

Of course, this assumes that you can update the Silverlight client; it's not clear from your question if you can.